# C++11 static_assert: Parameterized error messages

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, assertions, static-assert

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048827/c11-static-assert-and-functions-to-be-used-therein/11048875#11048875) I wanted to use static_assert to restrict a template parameter to be a specific subtype. The question was answered, the code for archieving that is as follows:

```
template <typename T> 
struct X { 
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Y,T>::value,"T must be derived from Y!");
};
```

Now, I want to make the error message more concise. I.e., I want to state which type is violating this constraint. E.g., if class `A` is not derived from `Y` and someone instanciates `X<A>`, then the error message should print "The type parameter must be derived from Y, but **A** isn't".

Is this somehow achievable with the standard library?

I see two challenges:

- Assembling strings at compiletime without using boost::mpl
- retrieving the name of the type with which T was instanciated. The name should be meaningful, ideally the same as used in the violating definition. I tried typeid(T).name() but it only returns the mangled name which is not acceptable. I remember that there was some kind of macro that returns the name of something, but I cannot recall that anymore.

Comment: Related (peraps even dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/q/6415186/34509

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do this. `static_assert` wants a string literal. You have no way to assemble the semantic identity of `T` and `Y` into the string literal.

You can hope that the compiler gives an easy to read backtrace of the template instantiation stack and gives you the value of `T` and `Y` template parameters of the enclosing class template instantiation.

Other people thought about this too, see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/5073 for example.

Comment: As always for diagnosis, it's a QOI.

Comment: what a shame. Why a literal, a compile time constant string would be better :(.

Comment: @gexicide It's not usually practical to form compile-time constant strings, anyway. (Besides literals, of course.) Printing the values of a sequence of arbitrary compile-time constant values and/or type-ids would be nice, though.

Comment: The link is dead now.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use
[BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/assert-msg.html). It accepts the generic types as parameters and tries to include the concrete type names in the error message.

More information and examples here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/assert-msg.html