# static_assert with dependent expression that is actually independent

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, static-assert

Consider the following template:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Now what?");
}
```

> The standard (§7.4) says:
>
> > [If the condition to static_assert is false] the program is ill-formed, and the resulting diagnostic message (1.4) shall include
> >     the text of the string-literal, […]

(Reference taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048906/560450)

In practice, the `static_assert` will not fail until we instantiate the function template `foo`, because the use othe the template parameter forces the compiler to evalute the condition only during two-phase lookup. Therefore, the code snippet above is not deemed ill-formed unless the function template is instantiated.

On the other hand, sizeof(T) > 0 in C++ [*by definition*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632075/560450). Therefore, the value of the condition is in fact independent of any template parameter! Is a "malicious" compiler allowed to take advantage of this fact, and reject the program as ill-formed, regardless whether `foo` is actually instantiated or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is allowed, but not required, to reject this.

§14.6 [temp.res]/p8:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that
>   template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no
>   diagnostic required.

An easy workaround:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_protector : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
void foo() {
  static_assert(foo_protector<T>::value, "Now what?");
}
```

The compiler is not allowed to reject `foo()`'s definition because there might be a specialization of `foo_protector`, not yet seen, such that its `value` member is `true`. As long as you don't actually write such a specialization, the `static_assert` will fire as expected.

Comment: Nice find, thanks! Now we only need to wait for C++ compilers equipped with automated theorem provers (and while we are at it, let's throw in a halting oracle for good measure) for this to happen in non-trivial circumstances. :-)