# CRTP applied on a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

Let's consider a CRTP template class Print which is meant to print the derived class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Print {
    auto print() const -> void;
    auto self() const -> T const & {
        return static_cast<T const &>(*this);
    }

private:
    Print() {}
    ~Print() {}

    friend T;
};
```

Because I want to specialize print based on the derived class like we could do this with an override, I don't implement the method yet.

We can wrap an Integer and do so for example:

```
class Integer :
    public Print<Integer>
{
public:
    Integer(int i) : m_i(i) {}

private:
    int m_i;

    friend Print<Integer>;
};

template <>
auto Print<Integer>::print() const -> void {
    std::cout << self().m_i << std::endl;
}
```

This works so far, now let's say I want to Print a generic version of a wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper :
  public Print<Wrapper<T>>
{
public:
    Wrapper(T value) : m_value(std::move(value)) {}

private:
    T m_value;

    friend Print<Wrapper<T>>;
};
```

If I specialize my print method with a specialization of the Wrapper it compile and works:

```
template <>
auto Print<Wrapper<int>>::print() const -> void
{
  cout << self().m_value << endl;
}
```

But if I want to say "for all specializations of Wrapper, do that", it doesn't work:

```
template <typename T>
auto Print<Wrapper<T>>::print() const -> void
{
  cout << self().m_value << endl;
}
```

If I run this over the following main function:

```
auto main(int, char**) -> int {
    auto i = Integer{5};
    i.print();

    auto wrapper = Wrapper<int>{5};
    wrapper.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler print:

```
50:42: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Print<Wrapper<T> >'
6:8: error: declaration of 'struct Print<Wrapper<T> >'
```

Why ? How can I do that ? Is it even possible or do I have to make a complete specialization of my CRTP class ?

Comment: Can you post a complete example? My initial hunch is that `auto self() const -> T` is the culprit, since you actually return whole object. Even though the body casts to a reference return would copy the object. I am to lazy to compile a live example to test.

Comment: I don't use trailing return types much, but does `self` return a copy of `this`?

Comment: Yes you're right I did a copy, I didn't pay attention, but on an int this doesn't solve anything anyway. I corrected it though and add a main function.

Comment: Yoda notation why like you? `auto print() const -> void;`

Comment: I like rust ... Well, that's pretty much the only reason :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a bit of a roundabout way so long as you're careful.

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uAYFTCrM35ZMyzwR)

Your `Print` class will rely on yet another class `PrintImpl` to do the printing.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class...>
struct always_false : std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct PrintImpl
{
    void operator()(const T&) const
    {
        static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "PrintImpl hasn't been specialized for T");
    }
};
```

You'll partially specialize this `PrintImpl` for your `Wrapper` class:

```
template<class T>
struct PrintImpl<Wrapper<T>>
{
    void operator()(const Wrapper<T>& _val) const
    {
       std::cout << _val.m_value;
    }
};
```

And make sure that `Wrapper` declares this `PrintImpl` to be a `friend`:

```
friend struct PrintImpl<Wrapper<T>>;
```

The `Print` class creates an instance of `PrintImpl` and calls `operator()`:

```
void print() const
{
    PrintImpl<T>{}(self());
}
```

This works so long as your specializations are declared before you actually instantiate an instance of the `Print` class.

---

You can also fully specialize `PrintImpl<T>::operator()` for your `Integer` class without writing a class specialization:

```
class Integer :
    public Print<Integer>
{
public:
    Integer(int i) : m_i(i) {}

private:
    int m_i;

    friend PrintImpl<Integer>;
};

template <>
void PrintImpl<Integer>::operator()(const Integer&  wrapper) const {
    std::cout << wrapper.m_i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way, isn't creating the PrintImpl each time the function is called a little bit heavy though ?

Comment: @Steranoid: It's a necessary evil because you cannot partially specialize functions. So we have to use a class.

Comment: 1. It is likely optimized away. 2. You can make the specialized function a static function instead--it wouldn't have to be `operator()`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `always_false` here?

Comment: @bipll: We want the primary `PrintImpl` template to always fail the static assertion (but only if it's instantiated). This is a standards-safe way of doing it. If we said `static_assert(false, ...)` then we'd always fail the static assert whether it was instantiated or not because it didn't depend on a template argument. If we said something like `static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, ...)` then this is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: "then we'd always fail the static assert because it didn't depend on a template argument" when it's not a specialization, eh?

Comment: @bipll: See my edit. It will fail with or without a specialization because it will fail whether the template is instantiated or not (because the assert doesn't rely on a template parameter) [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t2dWGZN6AuZSCw8N)

Comment: @bipll What is meant is this: The compiler parses the `PrintImpl` template, sees a `static_assert` that does not depend on template parameters, so it evaluates it immediately. You immediately get an error, no matter how/if you use or specialize `PrintImpl` anywhere.

Comment: @AndyG Why is `static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, ...)` UB?

Comment: I think I will prefer a partial specialization for my template because with your solution, one will have to specialize a whole new class just to do so every time, with a specific partial specialization, one would have to specialize a whole class only if he wants to use this crtp on a template. To ensure that all Print object have the same methods, we can delegate things to a helper class that we specilize only if needed as you proposed. This gives us this : [Code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rXnLygxwUKXAf5XO)

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Correction: ill-formed no diagnostic required. Since we can prove that `sizeof(T) != 0` for all `T` as required by the standard (with some exceptions for empty base subobject optimization), there's no `T` such that the primary template is valid. See [temp.res] "Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked. The program is
ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: [...] no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated."

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343811/static-assert-with-dependent-expression-that-is-actually-independent

Comment: @Steranoid: I appreciate your feedback, however I don't see how your solution doesn't also require the same amount of partial specialization.

Comment: @AndyG because it's less verbose when it comes to implement it for one function only : [Code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jIEt8wkhuoGkaG2d)

Comment: @Steranoid: Fair enough, I see your point. I think that we can get the full function specialization you desire as well as the safety of the `static_assert` from my code (and no extra inheritance): https://wandbox.org/permlink/VFPy7rTdXm9I3fYh

Comment: @AndyG Oh, I didn't even considered it like this, yeah I think this is perfect, you want to propose this final solution so I can close this post ?

Comment: @Steranoid: Done